# Why do iphone images have the wrong orientation?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dragonfly-gem

Our ruby/rails web app supports taking images using mobile devices. However, when taking an image using an iphone the orientation in the web view is sideways when viewed through [android, windows, mac]. When viewed through an iphone, the image has the correct orientation. If I download the image and open it in chrome it has the correct orientation.

We use dragonfly for image viewing. I am leaning towards this being the route cause... Any ideas?

```
%input{:accept => "image/*", :name => "image", :capture => "camera", :type => "file", :style =>'display:none;', :id => 'take_pic_master_btn'}
```

Comment: I do not like being edited.

Comment: Then Stack Overflow is probably not the place for you. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing. We expect proper grammar and punctuation, which includes correct capitalization of proper names such as "iPhone", "Android", "Windows", etc. It will happen if you don't do it initially as it's part of the directive of Stack Overflow.

Comment: The problem with that is intent. I personally do not like iphones... So, i purposefully do not use their weird capitalization standard. When you change things like that, it changes the authors intent. Unfortunately, SO does not give me the option to accept changes individually.

Comment: Then you must not like "Windows", "Android", or any of the other names either. Stack Overflow is a reference site for programming problems and their solutions. As a reference-book like site, correctness is going to trump your opinions of Apple or other vendors. Feel free to take it to [meta], however remember this isn't a discussion board, it's a reference site.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280581/grammar-corrections-good-or-bad would be a good starting point.

Comment: I'll change windows and android if you change 'the Tin Man' to 'The Tin Man' OR 'the tin man'.

Comment: Ultimately I guess I'm just upset with an all-or-nothing approach to editing. Ill bring it up on meta. Thanks TTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `auto_orient`?

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Dragonfly::Model

  dragonfly_accessor :image do
    after_assign do |attachment|
      # Auto orien
      attachment.convert! '-auto-orient'
    end
  end
end
```

This is on "playback" but you could use this before save as well.

Comment: Turns out this is the solution. I tested the wrong branch. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When iOS captures an image it stores the image as-is with an orientation flag to tell the system how to rotate the image for viewing.

I see you have an answer you like, but another possibility is to re-render the image on iOS to have portrait orientation baked in, before you send the image to the server.